# How to put a hard coded menue in bootstrap navbar while having other data from json

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting my menu and menu items from JSON data and want to hardcode a menu i.e logout in my case I have tried but it's coming before all the JSON menu loaded

```js
var data = {
  "Drill Down Reports": [{
      "type": "Sales Drilldown Counterwise Bet Dates",
      "link": "Sales Drilldown Counterwise Bet Dates.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "Sales Drilldown Billwise Bet Dates",
      "link": "Sales Drilldown Billwise Bet Dates.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "Sales Drilldown Itemwise for Date",
      "link": "Sales Drilldown Itemwise for Date"
    }
  ],
  "Reports": [{
      "type": "Date wise Outlet wise Sales Summary",
      "link": "Date wise Outlet wise Sales Summary.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "Date wise OL Wise Counter wise Sales",
      "link": "Date wise OL Wise Counter wise Sales.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "MRPL Store Sales With Date",
      "link": "MRPL Store Sales With Date.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "Outlet Sales Summary Pai chart",
      "link": "Outlet Sales Summary Pai chart.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "Payment mode wise Graph layout",
      "link": "Payment mode wise Graph layout.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "Hourly wise Sales Bet Dates",
      "link": "Hourly wise Sales Bet Dates.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "Hourly sales Outlet wise Date wise",
      "link": "Hourly sales Outlet wise Date wise.jsp"
    }
  ],


}

$(document).ready(function() {

  for (var item in data) {
    var _menu = "";
    var _submenuData = data[item];
    if (_submenuData.length > 0) {
      var _submenu = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < _submenuData.length; i++) {
        _submenu += "<a class='dropdown-item' href='" + _submenuData[i]["link"] + "'>" + _submenuData[i]["type"] + "</a>";
      }

      _menu = "<li class='nav-item dropdown'>" +
        "<a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href='' id='navbardrop' data-toggle='dropdown'> " + item + " </a>" +
        "<div id='drop' class='dropdown-menu'>" +
        _submenu +
        "</div>" +
        "</li>";
    } else {
      _menu = "<li class='nav-item'>" +
        "<a class='nav-link' href='LogoutServlet'> " + item + " </a>" +
        "</li>"; //here at href i want to use the link i am getting in json
    }

    $("#navbarId").append(_menu);
  }

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark navbar fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="welcome.jsp">HOME</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul id="navbarId" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="LogoutServlet">logout</a> //want to align this Logout after Masters
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The logout is coming before all the JSON data loaded, so
what I want to achieve is to align Logout after masters

I know its a small thing but I have tried hard and not getting the solution.
anyone out there with any suggestion or help please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = {
  "Drill Down Reports": [{
      "type": "Sales Drilldown Counterwise Bet Dates",
      "link": "Sales Drilldown Counterwise Bet Dates.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "Sales Drilldown Billwise Bet Dates",
      "link": "Sales Drilldown Billwise Bet Dates.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "Sales Drilldown Itemwise for Date",
      "link": "Sales Drilldown Itemwise for Date"
    }
  ],
  "Reports": [{
      "type": "Date wise Outlet wise Sales Summary",
      "link": "Date wise Outlet wise Sales Summary.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "Date wise OL Wise Counter wise Sales",
      "link": "Date wise OL Wise Counter wise Sales.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "MRPL Store Sales With Date",
      "link": "MRPL Store Sales With Date.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "Outlet Sales Summary Pai chart",
      "link": "Outlet Sales Summary Pai chart.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "Payment mode wise Graph layout",
      "link": "Payment mode wise Graph layout.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "Hourly wise Sales Bet Dates",
      "link": "Hourly wise Sales Bet Dates.jsp"
    },
    {
      "type": "Hourly sales Outlet wise Date wise",
      "link": "Hourly sales Outlet wise Date wise.jsp"
    }
  ],


}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var _menu = "";
  for (var item in data) {
  
    var _submenuData = data[item];
    if (_submenuData.length > 0) {
      var _submenu = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < _submenuData.length; i++) {
        _submenu += "<a class='dropdown-item' href='" + _submenuData[i]["link"] + "'>" + _submenuData[i]["type"] + "</a>";
      }

      _menu = "<li class='nav-item dropdown'>" +
        "<a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href='' id='navbardrop' data-toggle='dropdown'> " + item + " </a>" +
        "<div id='drop' class='dropdown-menu'>" +
        _submenu +
        "</div>" +
        "</li>";
    } else {
     
    }

    $("#navbarId").append(_menu);
  }
 var _logout = "<li class='nav-item'>" +
        "<a class='nav-link' href='LogoutServlet'>  Log out  </a>" +
        "</li>";
         $("#navbarId").append(_logout);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark navbar fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="welcome.jsp">HOME</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul id="navbarId" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
     
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Simply append logout menu after iterating the json data.